# Using ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM to filter out System Apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

I am using following code to differentiate between User Installed App and System App:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
{
    if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)
        Log.d(TAG, "Installed package (System) :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    else
        Log.d(TAG, "Installed package (User) :" + packageInfo.packageName);
}
```

How ever this gives some apps as User Installed Apps which are actually not. Following is the LogCat in my emulator:

```
Installed package (User) :com.android.smoketest
Installed package (User) :com.android.widgetpreview
Installed package (User) :com.example.android.livecubes
Installed package (User) :com.example.android.apis
Installed package (User) :com.android.gesture.builder
Installed package (User) :com.example.android.softkeyboard
Installed package (User) :com.android.smoketest.tests
Installed package (User) :faheem.start
```

Ideally, only last application should be output in User Installed Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Uddhav Gautam

I think your answer is wrong in multiple places.

1. the code you site in the link specifically states:

   > /**
   >        * Flags associated with the application.  Any combination of

which means your third example (following the OR) is completely wrong since the value 0x1001 has the 1 bit set but is definitely not equal to 1

2. Since the result of an and operation against the mask 0x1 is always either 0x0 or 0x1, there is no difference between != 0 and == 1

that said I do agree that the correct way to test for any bit being set is:

```
if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)
```